# Generate JUnit report for individual Test case in Java

Tags: java, jenkins, junit, testcase, test-suite

I am making an framework that internally uses REST Assured. This framework will have the 4 @Test methods for CRUD operations. These methods are called individually by the user. I want the method should generate the JUnit report for each test case which the user calls(GET/PUT/PUT/DELETE).
I tried using *surefire-report* plugin. As I have read, that will generate report only when we build the project(running all the Test suite)(please correct if I am wrong).
I want particularly my framework should generate the JUnit style report(for jenkins integration) at the end of each call. I used the *ExtentReport*, but thats not what I wanted actually.
Please suggest any way to get the work done.

Comment: fyi you can use the HTML Publisber plugin and directly link extent reports.

Comment: No more I will be using ExtentReport. I got to generate specifically JUnit style report in future.